# Add a signature field in my XML view with Odoo 16 and custom modules

Tags: xml, module, odoo, digital-signature, odoo-16

I am developing a custom module for Odoo 16.
This module adds a form to the `/open-account-b2b` route that creates a contact and if desired, also creates a SEPA payment mandate. 
I know that on Odoo, it's possible to have a signature field where you can draw, upload or automatically generate a signature.
I'd like to add this field to my XML view to eventually generate a document for setting up the SEPA mandate.

However, I can't figure out how to do it.

Here's my XML view:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<odoo>
    <template id="form_view" name="B2B Registration Form">
        <t t-call="website.layout">
            <form action="/submit-registration-form" method="post" class="registration_form">
                <img src="/b2b_registration/static/src/img/ellispe_black.png"
                    alt="Logo Ellispe Industries"
                    id="ellipse_logo" />
                <h1>Formulaire d'ouverture de compte B2B</h1>

                <t t-if="error_msg">
                    <div class="alert alert-danger">
                        <t t-esc="error_msg" />
                    </div>
                </t>

                <div>
                    <label class="required">Civilité</label>
                    <select name="title">
                        <option value="3" selected="selected">Monsieur</option>
                        <option value="1">Madame</option>
                        <option value="2">Mademoiselle</option>
                    </select>
                </div>

                <div>
                    <label class="required">Représentant</label>
                    <input type="text" name="fullname"
                        placeholder="ex: Pierre DUPONT" required="1" />
                </div>

                <div>
                    <label class="required">Email</label>
                    <input type="email" name="email"
                        placeholder="" required="1" id="email-field" />
                </div>

                <div>
                    <label class="required">Téléphone</label>
                    <input type="tel" name="phone"
                        placeholder="" required="1" id="phone-field" />
                    <span>06 ou 07 pour recevoir les notifications de livraison par SMS</span>
                </div>

                <br class="space" />

                <div>
                    <label class="required">Raison Sociale</label>
                    <input type="text" name="company_name"
                        placeholder="" required="1" />
                </div>

                <div>
                    <label class="not-required">Site Web</label>
                    <input type="text" name="website"
                        placeholder="" />
                </div>

                <div>
                    <label class="required">SIRET</label>
                    <input type="text" name="company_registry"
                        placeholder="" required="1" />
                </div>

                <div>
                    <label class="required">N° de TVA</label>
                    <input type="text" name="vat"
                        placeholder="" required="1" />
                </div>

                <div>
                    <label class="required">Poste Occupé</label>
                    <input type="text" name="function"
                        placeholder="" required="1" />
                </div>

                <div id="billing_address_fields">
                    <label class="required">Adresse de facturation</label>
                    <input type="text" name="street"
                        placeholder="" />
                    <span>Rue *</span>

                    <input type="text" name="street2"
                        placeholder="" />
                    <span>Rue 2</span>

                    <input type="text" name="zip"
                        placeholder="" />
                    <span>Code Postal *</span>

                    <input type="text" name="city"
                        placeholder="" />
                    <span>Ville *</span>

                    <select name="country_id">
                        <option value="75" selected="selected">France</option>
                    </select>
                    <span>Pays *</span>
                </div>

                <div class="row">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="same_address" name="same_address" value="yes" />
                    <label for="same_address">L'adresse de facturation est différente de l'adresse
                        de
                        livraison</label>
                </div>

                <div id="delivery_address_fields">
                    <label class="required">Adresse de livraison</label>
                    <input type="text" name="shipping_street"
                        placeholder="" />
                    <span>Rue *</span>

                    <input type="text" name="shipping_street2"
                        placeholder="" />
                    <span>Rue 2</span>

                    <input type="text" name="shipping_zip" placeholder=""
                    />
                    <span>Code Postal *</span>

                    <input type="text" name="shipping_city" placeholder=""
                    />
                    <span>Ville *</span>

                    <select name="shipping_country_id">
                        <option value="75" selected="selected">France</option>
                    </select>
                    <span>Pays *</span>
                </div>

                <div class="row" id="sepa_auth_row">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="sepa_auth" name="sepa_auth" value="yes"
                        checked="True" />
                    <label for="sepa_auth">J'autorise Ellipse à mettre en place le prélèvement
                        automatique</label>
                </div>
                <div id="bank_fields">
                    <label class="required">Informations bancaires</label>
                    <input type="text" name="iban_number"
                        placeholder="" />
                    <span>IBAN *</span>

                    <input type="text" name="bic_number"
                        placeholder="" />
                    <span>BIC *</span>

                    <input type="text" name="bank_name"
                        placeholder="" />
                    <span>Nom de la banque *</span>
                </div>

                <div class="row">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="cgv_checkbox" name="cgv_checkbox" value="yes"
                        required="1" />
                    <label for="cgv_checkbox">J'accepte les <a
                            href="https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hSY4IA0IwKyoVagGN_Ro_NUrjx9naT1u/view?usp=sharing"
                            target="_blank" id="cgv-link">Conditions
                            Générales de Vente</a> d'Ellipse Industries *</label>
                </div>

                <!-- Add signature field here -->

                <input id="submit-btn" type="submit" value="Soumettre" />
            </form>
        </t>
    </template>
</odoo>
```

If you need more information, don't hesitate to contact us.

Thank you very much.